# Render a variable during creation of anonymous PHP function

Tags: php, declaration, anonymous-function

I'm trying to get a simple sort function going using anonymous functions.  One each for asc and desc sorting.

Is it possible to render the **$sortBy** variable right away when the function is created, but still have **$x** and **$y** passed in when called later?   I want to be able to dynamically pass in a key when creating these.

```
$sortBy = 'some_key';

// descending
$sort['desc'] = function($x, $y) {
  if($x['data'][$sortBy] == $y['data'][$sortBy])
    return 0;

  return ($x['data'][$sortBy] > $y['data'][$sortBy]) ? -1 : 1;
};

uasort($arrayToSort, $sort[$order]);
```

**EDIT:**
I'm passing this array as a param to uasort().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a variable in enclosing scope using the [`use` keyword (*Example #3 Closures and scoping*)](http://php.net/functions.anonymous):

```
$sortBy = 'some_key';

$sort['desc'] = function($x, $y) use ($sortBy) {
    // implementation
};
```