# PHP access variable from anonymous function

Tags: php, function, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Render a variable during creation of anonymous PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797482/render-a-variable-during-creation-of-anonymous-php-function)

I am still quite new with PHP and this bothers me:

```
class Controller {
    ...
    ...
    function _activateCar() {
        $car_id = $this->data['car']->getId();
        // $car_id == 1
        $active_car = array_filter($this->data['cars'], function($car){
            // $car_id undefined
            return $car->getId() == $car_id;
        });
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Why can't the function inside array_filter access the `$car_id` variable? Keeps saying undefined.

Is there an other way to make `$car_id` accessible than to make a `$_GET['car_id'] = $car_id;`? Using the `global` keyword didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `use($car_id)` to your anonymous function, like so:

```
$active_car = array_filter($this->data['cars'], function($car) use($car_id){
    // $car_id undefined
    return $car->getId() == $car_id;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Anonymous functions can import select variables with the `use` keyword:

```
$active_car = array_fiter($this->data['cars'],function($car) use ($car_id) {
    return $car->getId() == $car_id;
});
```